# For some RV's $X$ with continuous density on $[0,1]$, is $\mathbb{E}|1/X|=\infty$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Recently [I tried to give an argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution#comment5158623_646467) for why, if $Z \sim N(0,1)$ denotes the standard normal, $\mathbb{E}|\frac{1}{Z}| = \infty$. However, in hindsight this argument does not seem to rely on many special properties of $Z$. As a test of my understanding, I have tried to make the following generalization:

> **Claim (Sufficient Condition for $\mathbb{E}|\frac{1}{X}| = \infty$):** For any random variable $X$ with a density $p(x)$ strictly positive and continuous at every point of $[0,1]$, it is the case that $\mathbb{E}|\frac{1}{X}|=\infty$.

**Question:** Is this claim true?

**Purported proof:** By [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{X}\right|\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{|x|}p(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{|x|}p(x) dx + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}p(x) dx + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}p(x) dx $$

Because $p(x)$ is strictly positive and continuous at every point of $[0,1]$, by the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) there exists an $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $p(x_0)>0$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$, $$p(x) \ge p(x_0)\,,$$ i.e. $\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]}p(x) =: p(x_0)$ can be well-defined.

Therefore, by [monotonicity and linearity of integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral) we have:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\frac{1}{X}\right|\right] \ge \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \left(\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]}p(x) \right) dx + \dots = \left( \min\limits_{x \in [0,1]} p(x) \right) \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx + \dots = \infty  $$ since the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$ is [well known to diverge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431737/integral-from-0-to-1-1-x). "$\square$"

Can this actually be correct? It seems odd to me that the behavior of the random variable on the interval $[0,1]$ alone can determine whether its reciprocal has finite expectation or not, especially for distributions which are not symmetric about $0$. It also seems too generally/widely applicable to too many important examples of (continuous) distributions to go completely unmentioned, for example, [in the Wikipedia page on inverse distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution).

Comment: The behavior of the density of $|X|$ near 0 is the main thing there. Loosely, if it doesn't "go to 0" quickly enough (it's not just that it needs have a limit of 0 there), the integral won't be finite.